# HTML table DnD event not triggered on border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have this table on my html page:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <label class="control-label" for="myTable">My Table</label>
    <div id="myTable" class="table-border" ondragover="event.preventDefault()">
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-muted">File Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to drag and drop draggable elements into this table, drop event is only triggered when I drop over table headers (File Name in this case), or the child rows if table is not empty:

```
$('#myTable').on('drop', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('dropped');
});
```

Any idea how can I make the entire border area droppable?

Thanks!